# Time complexity of this power function

Tags: go, big-o

I'm having this code to calculate the power of certain number

```
func power(x, n int) int {
    if n == 0 {
        return 1
    }

    if n == 1 {
        return x
    }

    if n%2 == 0 {
        return power(x, n/2) * power(x, n/2)
    } else {
        return power(x, n/2) * power(x, n/2) * x
    }
}
```

[go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/https://play.golang.org/p/F4MLmPe_ciM):

So, the total number of execution is 1 + 2 + 4 + ... + 2^k

and according to the formula of Geometric progression

a(1-r^n) / (1-r)

the sum of the execution times will be 2^k, where k is the height of the binary tree

Hence the time complexity is 2^logn

Am I correct? Thanks :)

Comment: Apparently, your formula for the summation of geometric series is wrong (when r > 1). The factor should be (r^n - 1) and (r - 1) [neither (1 - r^n) nor (1 - r)].

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma oh but I referenced this formula from wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Another way of thinking on complexity of recursive functions is (amount of calls)**(height of recursive tree)

In each call you make two calls which divide n by two so the height of tree is logn so the time complexity is 2**(logn) which is O(n)

See a much more formal proof here:

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/69539/time-complexity-of-recursive-power-code

Comment: If you look closely, then you find that the fn does not make 2 calls at a time. Every time it goes through an if-else block. That means either n%2 == 0 or n%2==1 not both. Right. So you can not simply consider it as 2 child calls.

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma But if you look even closer in both cases there are two calls:
`return power(x, n/2) * power(x, n/2)`
or
`return power(x, n/2) * power(x, n/2) * x`

Comment: Oh yeah I admit it. I did not notice that comes twice using * operator. Apology for my actions and have recoverd your reputations.

Answer (score -1):

Every time you are dividing n by 2 unless n <= 1. So think how many times you can reduce n to 1 only by dividing by 0? Let's see,

n = 26
n1 = 13
n2 = 6 (take floor of 13/2)
n3 = 3
n4 = 1 (take floor of 3/2)

Let's say x_th power of 2 is greater or equal to x. Then,

```
2^x >= n
or, log2(2^x) = log2(n)
or, x = log2(n)
```

That is how you find the time complexity of your algorithm as log2(n).

Comment: No, you just took into consideration the amount of calls until n becomes 1, which is indeed log2(n). But you also need to take the amount of calls in each call, which is 2, therefore the time complexity is O(n)